# C# PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics.DrawRectangle prints incorrect size

Tags: c#, drawrectangle

I expected the code below to draw a rectangle 3 inches wide by 1 inch tall.  Instead, the actual rectangle on the printed page is 4 inches wide by 2 inches tall.

Every rectangle I attempt to draw is always 1 inch wider and taller than I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

What addition properties in PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics should I be setting to get a correctly sized rectangle on the printed page?

```
void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightGray, 1, 1, 3, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below fixed this issue. I suspect the default pen width is 1, which is interpreted as 1 inch. That made the rectangle extra big. Specifying a pen width of 0 fixed it.

```
void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.LightGray, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 1, 1, 3, 1);
}
```